# What order should authors be on arXiv.org for equal contribution authorships?

Tags: authorship, arxiv, author-order

If everyone made an equal contribution in effort to write the paper, but no on the team but myself decided to post the paper on arXiv and no one opposed my decision to arXiv post, should I myself, the poster, or the corresponding author be the first author, or should the authors be listed alphabetically? At this point there's not yet any monetary or power incentive to be first or last and I don't expect there to be any in the future.

Comment: arXiv isn't relevant here. Just ask yourself "in which order should the authors be in this paper". It doesn't matter whether you are posting it on arXiv, or putting a manuscript on your own home page, or submitting it for publication to a journal.

Comment: @JukkaSuomela, your comment might be better as a formal answer.

Comment: What is the subject area of the paper?

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: @Heutl The subject area matters because different subject areas use different conventions for determining the order of authors. For instance, most of math uses alphabetical order (irrespective of the contribution), and in some disciplines, the last position carries a special significance.

Comment: @Uwe: I did not mean the subject area, but the order of authors in arxiv.

Comment: @Heutl Why should the importance of the order of authors be different for arxiv and for other publications?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If everyone made an equal contribution, you can put that information in the footnote. 
In a very famous (in the AI-related research) paper [ADAM: a method for stochastic optimisation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.6980.pdf) you can encounter the following line:

> ∗Equal contribution. Author ordering determined by coin flip over a Google Hangout.

I'd say randomisation is a fair way to go.
If you want to be more specific, [here](https://www.epj.org/images/stories/faq/examples-of-author-contributions.pdf) you can check examples for contribution statements.
There's a whole taxonomy for that: [CRediT author contribution statements](https://casrai.org/credit/).
You can place these contributions e.g. just before the references section in the paper.

As Jukka already mentioned in the comment, arXiv does not matter in this case. 
I think the order should always reflect the real contribution (if possible).
All in all, it's good that you care about such things - good luck with your research.

Comment: I would advise to avoid Google Hangout (if possible) so that you do not have to mention it. In a scientific paper, there should not be advertisments for for-profit-companies unless mentioning them is really necessary.

Comment: My impression is that randomization, while it has some benefits, is not very common; alphabetical is still the more common practice when authors contributed equally.  So if you randomize the ordering, people who just see the citation are likely to think "it's not alphabetical, therefore the ordering must be significant, and the first-named author must have made the most important contributions".  They would only see your note if they actually started to read the paper.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably the authors will have all agreed to an author list, and this should be the one used on arXiv, irrespective of who is posting on arXiv or who is the corresponding author.